# Does the $length function in QGIS field calculator support LinestringZ?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, 3d

I have a shapefile with a `MultiLinestringZ` geometry type that I created using the grass v.drape function to attach z-values from a DEM. In order to calculate the 3d length of a line segment, can I use the `$length` function in the QGIS field calculator, or will this function only report the 2d length?

Comment: A simple test with two identical features but with wildly different Z values at the points gives the same `$length` value. Maybe submit a documentation issue to make this explicit in the help if it is the case? Also, I can't find a function or plugin that says it can measure 3d line lengths for things with Z geometry.

Comment: @Spacedman you are right, I did this simple test over a volcano (one 2d one 3d) and they yielded the same length when length was calculated via $length function in the field calculator. I'll submit a documentation issue to try and clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `$length` function only reports lengths from 2d geometries.